# Should I save image url in the data base?

Tags: php, sql

Here is the situation:

I want to add the ability to add/edit recommendations in my new site. I want that every recommendation will have a photo, which if uploaded is shown that way and if not, shown other default image.

The question is, should I save the url of the image I upload in the database? Or should my getImage function just return the url to an image as it is by the unique id of the recommendation (like "/photos/$id.jpg")?

Comment: You don't loop, you give a string with different id. If I understood what you meant (you can't store an image in the DB just a url to its location)

Comment: I think it's a valid question, although a better phrasing might have been 'Is there a benefit to images having descriptive file names instead of arbitrary numbers?'

Comment: IMHO it is a pointless question, in each case you have a reference to the image, $id.jpg or my-image.jpg is the same thing. the only difference is that in the first case, you are most probably renaming the image-file-name to user-id and in second you must sanitize it. so in the end not a real difference

Comment: So are you definitively saying that there are absolutely no usability or seo benefits to using descriptive file names for images? I'm genuinely interested myself now!

Comment: @Vadiklk: just for the record images can be stored in database, but it is not what i meant. ;)

Comment: @shanethehat: SEO benefits? hmm maybe using proper `alt` tag? and what about db indexing maybe you can use an adjacent column where search for sensitive infos, maybe with `fulltext` search?

Comment: Of course you should also alt and title your image tags, but it seems the file name is a contributing factor: http://fatfreeguide.com/seo-training/optimizing-images-for-seo/#Use+fully+descriptive+file+names

Comment: @shanethehat: it is a myth! ;-)

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but source? ;)

Comment: @shanethehat: yeah my friend it is right, but only if don't have alt or title setted, so you don't really need to rely on image-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewritten for clarity and detail...

I think that as long as the additional weight in your database is not an issue (and you state that it is not) then using a descriptive file name is better than an id number for these reasons:

**SEO:**  File names are one of the factors that search engines use when indexing your site's content.  Although it is only a small part, and for images the alt, title and description properties carry more weight, it makes no sense to me to deliberately omit potential data unnecessarily.

**Usability:** From you own point of view, if you need to update an image at a later date it is going to make your life easier if the file names are easy to read.  This will save you time that you would otherwise need to check which file you need to work with.

Comment: It won't cause any problems, because it is limited on a logical 1000 photos (way less). But what will be a plus in this flexibility?

Comment: My first though was readability, both for you browsing your folder, and for image search engines being able to read a descriptive file name when indexing your site. Flexibility may have been a poor choice of word.